# Load-balancing with a parameter in a highly-concurrent scenario

Tags: algorithm, load-balancing

Let's say there are two service clusters A and B, namely there are tens of or hundreds of hosts in both A and B, and of course sometimes some hosts may restart or be removed or added. running and . Services in A do RPC calls to Services in B with a method doRemoteCall(String shopId, ..). It is in a highly concurrently scenario, the cluster qps could be 100k or more.

Now I hope that the load balancing for A to do RPC calls to B follows the three rules below:

1. RPC requests with the same shopId can be routed to the same host(idealy) or the same groups of hosts on B with high probability(of course, the higher, the better, ideally it could be 100%)
2. the RPC calls are relatively evenly distributed among the hosts on B.
3. the routing decision in hosts on A are made independently by each host, without knowing information of other hosts (because it could be complex for each host to get information from other hosts, especially in highly concurrent and dynamic(hosts leave or join ocassionally) scenario)

Answer (score 0):

The magic google words are "consistent hashing".

In the classic [consistent hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing) scheme, each A host would do this (the constants 256 and 64-bit are arbitrary, but appropriate for this problem size):

- For each host B and all k in 1...256, calculate a 64-bit server hash H<sub>s</sub> = hash(B,k)
- For each user id, calculate a 64-bit hash H<sub>u</sub>
- Assign the user id to the host with the smallest H<sub>s</sub> such that H<sub>s</sub> >= H<sub>u</sub>.  If there is none, use the highest H<sub>s</sub>.

Of course, the set of server hashes only needs to be modified when B hosts go up or down.

I usually prefer [rendezvous hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendezvous_hashing), but with hundreds of hosts to balance over, it gets slow:

- For each user id, for each host, calculate a 64-bit hash(userid,host)
- Assign the userid to the host with the smallest hash.

Comment: sorry, it should be shopId, not userId coz if a large count of same userId are in RPC requests in a short period, it might be regarded as a DDoS. 

I thought about consistent hashing, but it is only for even distribution of shopIds, not requests, coz some shopIds may appear more than others.

Comment: Also, the range of active shopIds may change, some shops may close while new shops may appear

Comment: It doesn't make any difference to the algorithm whether it's shopid or userid.  Neither of these systems requires storing shopids, so it doesn't matter that they open and close.

Comment: yes, it doesn't matter whether it is shopid or userId. I note it just to avoid talking about DDOS. The problem is the consistent hashing can evenly distributed the key, but what if different keys have different QPS?

Comment: the problem is consistent hashing can evenly distribute key space, but here we want to evenly distributed requests, not key space coz different key have different QPS

Comment: If you read the wikipedia article on consistent hashing, it mentions techniques for dealing with problems like that.  You don't need to worry about it as long as you have a lot more shops than servers, though.  If you don't then hash *both* shop Id and user id.

Comment: Thimmermans thanks, there is a variant, how about if there are two keys shopId and goodsId, and we hope requests with the same shopId and goodsId fall to the same host or a few hosts as possible as it can?